# Linking MAPISendMailW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors, mapi

Im working on a program that shall open the default mail client to send a message with an attachment.  I'm on `Windows x64 (8.1)`, using `VS2012`, building for `x64`.  I figured the right way to be to use `MAPISendMailW`.

I added `MAPI32.lib` to the project settings (`Linker->AdditionalDependencies`), and building with `/VERBOSE:LIB` shows, that it tries to find `MAPISendMailW` in `MAPI32.lib`.  Still I get

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol MAPISendMailW referenced in function ...`

So finally I checked the content of MAPI32.lib via

`dumpbin.exe -headers MAPI32.lib >> to_some_textfile.txt`

and - oh, well - there is no `MAPISendMailW`.

What do I have to do to use `MAPISendMailW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with VS2k10(Ultimate) and VS2k13(Ultimate). In the former it doesn't compile since it's not present in `MAPI.h`, while in the latter the include file is not even present.

So how did you get past by the compilation phase? Did you define the function header? Because I find it strange that the function definition is in VS2k12 include files but not in the corresponding lib files.

Install [Windows 8 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) on the computer where you try building the app.

Or, you could try the alternative, dynamically loading (at runtime) the `MAPISendMailW` function from `mapi32.dll` (and no longer rely on `MAPI.h` and `MAPI32.lib`) using [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)/[GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx), but most likely you'll have to define additional stuff (like `lpMapiMessageW` structure) besides the function pointer definition:

```
typedef ULONG (WINAPI *MAPISendMailWPtr)(_In_ LHANDLE lhSession, _In_ ULONG_PTR lUIParam, _In_ lpMapiMessageW lpMessage, _In_ FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved);
```

@EDIT1: Attaching some sample code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MAPI.h>

// Some lines of code
HMODULE mapi32Dll = NULL;
LPMAPISENDMAILW MAPISendMailWPtr = NULL;

if ((mapi32Dll = LoadLibrary("mapi32.dll")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error %d loading lib\n", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
if ((MAPISendMailWPtr = (LPMAPISENDMAILW)GetProcAddress(mapi32Dll, "MAPISendMailW")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error %d loading func\n", GetLastError());
    FreeLibrary(mapi32Dll);
    return 0;
}

//ULONG result = MAPISendMailWPtr(....)
// Some more lines of code
FreeLibrary(mapi32Dll);
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you - Win8SDK is installed, but I'm actually already working on Win10.  Still: it takes the headers and the import library directly from the Win8SDK.

I also find it very strange, so I guess my best bet will be `LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress`.

Comment: P.S.: see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\MAPI.h` at http://pastebin.com/kqUfMUB8 - Line 139ff: structure declaration; Lines 263ff: closure definition, type definition, function declaration

Comment: I have installed W8SDK. After looking at [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802867(v=vs.85).aspx)(there's no .lib file mentioned in the _Requirements_ section) and also in the header file I noticed that the function is defined as a pointer (just as I defined it), so it's ment to be used this way. So, include `MAPI.h` for all the definition, then `MAPI32.lib` is not required (at least for this func), but use dynamic loading instead.

Comment: I'm trying this right now, but it's no fun.  M$'s memory management and their structures are driving me crazy.